# Read images which are store in the iphone device

Tags: iphone, ipad

i have a project in which i have to read images which are store in iphone devices.i have no idea about that can someone help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: you question is not cleared..store means photos in device?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), this lets users pick images from their device. (Library, Camera Roll etc.)